# TeX display problem

Tags: bug, status-completed, math-display

Sometimes maths seems to have strange and squashed spacing, but the problem is intermittent. For example, this is what [Fitting a fixed, exponential relationship between categories with categorical data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1261/) looked like for a while on Chrome today:
[alt text http://robjhyndman.com/Untitled.png](http://robjhyndman.com/Untitled.png)
But a few minutes later it looked fine. Is this a known problem and is someone working on it?

Comment: If I see this problem, then open the same page in firefox, followed by a refresh in chrome, the problem disappears. Is anyone from the SE team reading this? Can someone please fix it?

Comment: @Jeff For me, all pc's with Ubuntu (9.10 and 10.10) and Chrome 7.0.517.41 always messes up the formula's. So I suggest trying a ubuntu live cd and install google-chrome for reproduction

Comment: I was having the same problem with Chrome 7.0.517.41 on Ubuntu. I've just restarted the browser to pick up an update to 7.0.517.44, and the problem seems to have gone.

Answer (score 5):

same thing here (ubuntu+chrome==formula no show) since 'it' updated TO chrome 7.0.517.41

EDIT: it all works perfectly on the same machine with FFox.

Answer (score 4):

For me (Chrome 7.0.517.41 on Fedora 13) LaTeX inserts does not appear or appear in random places. On the same machine Firefox 3.6.10 manages to render it well.

Comment: Try Chrome 7.0.517.44; the update has fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Indeed, things got better after auto update; I forgot to write it here.

Answer (score 3):

This morning I had the same problem in chrome for this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3708/forecasting-unemployment-rate/3717#3717), I checked and the tex did render correctly in IE version 8 (although I was surprised how much slower it was in IE than in Chrome, alot slower).[image]

Comment: By the time I finished posting my comment it has already corrected itself.

Comment: In my case after today Chrome update I can see only white space instead of equations.

Comment: Having this problem, too.  Chrome 7.0.517.41 on Windows 7.

Comment: ... and now it's randomly fixed after visiting Meta.

Answer (score 3):

I see this problem with Chrome 14.0.835.186 on Ubuntu 11.04 (classic mode).

Today is the first time it has occurred, but when it did, only one of two uses of `\sum()` had smushed brackets (see below). The question [Calculating likelihood from RMSE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16508/calculating-likelihood-from-rmse) (I edited the first equation to `\sum\left(...\right)` thinking it would help, but it didn't).

[image]

Comment: Notice the *i* beneath the $\Sigma$ in the first equation: it appears to be almost in the correct location with respect to the summand and clearly is shifted left of center.  This suggests that the positioning algorithm thinks the $\Sigma$ is much smaller than it really is, but then rendered it at the correct size, fixing the bottom left corner position.  The only apparent difference between the two "\sum" commands is that one of them initiates the $\TeX$ line and the other does not.

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce this -- how do we reproduce this?

Comment: Look at a recent question in Chrome. Right now, http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3727/approximating-prn-leq-x-leq-m-for-a-discrete-distribution is a mess on chrome on my PC.

Comment: For me, all pc's with Ubuntu (9.10 and 10.10) and Chrome 7.0.517.41 always messes up the formula's. So I suggest trying a ubuntu live cd and install google-chrome for reproduction

Comment: I am seeing this problem with all formulae on the site. I am using Chrome 7.0.517.41 on Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not getting *any* equations at the moment. I see the TeX code for a few seconds, then this (Firefox 3.6.3 on Windows XP):

[image]

A "Failed to load" message appears in the bottom left corner of the screen, but goes away before i have time to read or capture it. It was ok earlier today (i have restarted my PC since then though).

UPDATE: Just rebooted my PC as I was having another, apparently unrelated, internet problem too (failing to contact the proxy server). It fixed that problem, but not this TeX display one.

2ND UPDATE (Following morning): It's OK now.